# remove ASP.net gridview header underline

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview in my asp.net page which is bound to sqldatasource.

when i tried to run page, it gives me underline for header in browser.

I don't want to show these underline for header. How to remove these header underline?

Comment: yes I am using styling... so is it happening coz of styling?

Comment: try text-decoration:none it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to inhibit underlining through the [HeaderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle.aspx) property of your grid view:

```
yourGridView.HeaderStyle.Font.Underline = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
th a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best, quickest way to resolve this issue is with the following code in your style sheet.

```
.GridView1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Nothing else is needed. This will allow you to set the no-underline option in a specific gridview. Like in my sample, the no underline is set to “GridView1” specifically.